# how to properly detect which mouse buttons are down in JavaFX

Tags: mouseevent, javafx-2

I've set a listener to my `Pane` so that it will detect mouse left and right buttons being down.
But when I hold left mouse button, then press right one, previous action seem to lose it's effect!

My code:

```
root.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
        if(t.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) f1();
        if(t.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) f2();
    }
});
```

while holding LMB I have `f1()` running, but when I push RMB it seems like new event totally overwrites previous one: only `f2()` runs.

How can I separate this two events?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`getButton()` can return only one value at a time. And it's latest pressed button. If you need to detect multiple mouse down being pressed you need to use corresponding functions:

```
root.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
        if (t.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
            System.out.println("rockets armed");
        }
        if (t.isSecondaryButtonDown()) {
            System.out.println("autoaim engaged");
        }
    }
});
```